# Why InsertAfter is not working in this case

Tags: jquery

I am showing a tips div and also I want to show an 'updated at' message at the end of the tips div. I am trying it this way:

```
var sampledata = [{
    "name": "John",
    "tip": "BUY 111",
    "time": "23-DEC"
},{
    "name": "John",
    "tip": "BUY 232",
    "time": "23-DEC"
}]

$(function() {
    $(".cl").html(""); // Clearing the HTML
    for (var i = 0; i < sampledata.length; i++) {
        var name = sampledata[i].name;
        var tip = sampledata[i].tip;
        var time = sampledata[i].time;
        var html = '';

        html += '<a href="#" class="c1">\
                <div class="stoc5 mt1">\
                    <div class="c1 fl wi80">\
                        <span class="fl c2 f14 ti-s mt">' + time + '</span>\
                        ' + tip + '\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="fr c2 f14 ti-s1 mt"></div>\
                    <div class="cl"></div>\
                </div>\
            </a>';
        $(".cl").append(html);
    }

    var newhtml =  '<div class="updated_attipes">23-DEC-2015</div>';
    $(".cl").insertAfter(newhtml);
});
```

Could you please let me know how to show updated div after the tips div ??
https://jsfiddle.net/pL7xugg1/28/

Answer (score 0):

The `insertAfter()` method is used to put a selected element after another, this means you're attempting to put the `.cl` element *after* a string which is in memory - hence it doesn't work.

You instead need to use just the `after()` method to place the generated HTML string after the `.cl` element. Try this:

```
$(".cl").after(newhtml);
```

Or you can continue to use the `insertAfter` method, but swap the order of the selector and variable:

```
$(newhtml).insertAfter(".cl");
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pL7xugg1/31/)

Comment: But why messages are displaying multiple times

Comment: That's because you're appending multiple `.cl` elements in the loop. Remove that element to stop that behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/pL7xugg1/32/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this the right format for jQuery  insertAfter()

```
$(newhtml).insertAfter(".cl");
```

refer jQuery Documentation of insertAfter http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/

There are two elements with `".cl"` class in the html. Check that is it desirable or not. Updated fiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/pL7xugg1/33/